# Firemonkey XE7 app doesn't work on Android 5

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a Firemonkey XE7 Android app and it works perfectly on Android 4.x 
But I tested it on Android 5 and it opens but after a while, it closes. 
The only thing the program does in that short time is one simple `ShowMessage();` and also making a file. 
I used the address of file like this :

```
filePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim;
```

Is the problem my filepath or `ShowMessage()` or ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to apply this hotfix: 
[ID: 30110, Beta hotfix for FireMonkey apps on Android 5.0 (Lollipop)](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110)